# Donde se especifican las clases bootstrap asociadas a una clase del Theme en Genexus

Tags: genexus

He visto que utilizando la clase "Container" en Genexus, al desplegar la página en el browser, aparece también la clase "container" de bootstrap. Esto pasa también con otras clases como "ContainerFluid" y botones entre otros.

Ahora, ¿donde puede encontrar esta asociación y cambiarla a mi conveniencia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí están documentadas las clases `Container`, `ContainerFluid`, y algunas otras, que tienen un mapping directo con clases de Bootstrap: [Reference of Theme Classes used in Responsive Web Applications](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?26076,Reference%20of%20Theme%20Classes%20used%20in%20Responsive%20Web%20Applications)

En el Target Environment Directory vas a encontrar un archivo llamado `gxtemplate.json`, donde se declaran estos mappings.

Si bien la arquitectura está diseñada para que en un futuro se soporte personalizar estos mappings, actualmente (GeneXus 15) no ofrecemos un mecanismo formal para que los desarrolladores puedan hacerlo.

Comment: Impecable Nicolas, gracias